# R Split values from a column and keep values class as factors not as list

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I know similar questions have been asked a lot, but I can't find one that satisfies my problem.

This is my problem.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Sample        Condition
RN001         1_healthy
RN002         14_healthy
RN008         20_disease
RN009         21_disease
RN0010        10_healthy
```

What I need is to split the values from the column **Condition** to get this:

```
Sample        Condition
RN001         healthy
RN002         healthy
RN008         disease
RN009         disease
RN0010        healthy
```

I already tried this:

```
data$Condition <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Condition), "_"), '[', 2)
```

but I obtain a list data structure like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "healthy"

[[2]]
[1] "healthy"

[[3]]
[1] "disease"

[[4]]
[1] "disease"
```

What I need is a data structure with class factor, like this:

```
 [1] healthy healthy disease disease healthy ...
 2 Levels:  healthy disease
```

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

We use `sub` to remove the prefix part by matching one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) followed by underscore (`_`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
data$Condition <- sub("^\\d+_", "", data$Condition)
data$Condition
#[1] "healthy" "healthy" "disease" "disease" "healthy"
```

---

The output of `lapply` is always a `list`.  So, if we need a `vector`, use `sapply`

```
data$Condition <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Condition), "_"), '[', 2)
```

Or `unlist` the `list` output from `lapply`

```
data$Condition <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Condition), "_"), '[', 2))
```